# Spring Security: Find Groups A User Belongs To?

Tags: spring-security, user-management

How do I find groups a user belongs to? I can use GroupManager.findAllGroups() then loop the group with GroupManager.findUsersInGroup(java.lang.String groupName). However, this is expensive. Do we have any straight forward method?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your database schema - if user table has a relation with groups, user.getGroups() should get you all the groups.

Comment: I am using default schema http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, there is no existing Spring Security API to do it, you may need to write the SQL yourself based on your database schema.